# I can not deploy laravel 5.3 app to server

Tags: laravel, web-deployment, laravel-5.3

I tried an old method like changing server.php to index.php and then ran the app but I am getting error like error.

```
The domain.com page isn’t working

domain.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

I am using godaddy shared hosting.. the server.php has changed in laravel 5.3

Comment: What's in your error log?

Comment: Also note that Laravel `5.3` now requires a PHP version of `>= 5.6.4`.

Comment: Glad you got it going and that I could help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Also note that Laravel 5.3 now requires a PHP version of >= 5.6.4
```

answered by camelCase

Answer (score 4):

Laravel `5.3` now requires a PHP version of `>= 5.6.4`. From the docs:

> You will need to make sure your server meets the following requirements:

- PHP >= 5.6.4
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP
- Extension Tokenizer PHP Extension